# Umlauts in Biblatex Entry Label

Tags: biblatex

Is it possible to have Biblatex generate a label using the correct first letters of the author's name (including umlauts)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[safeinputenc,backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Article{Morgan,
  Title   = {Article title},
  Author  = {M{\"u}ller, John},
  Journal = {Journal title},
  Year    = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

The correct label should be `Mül14`.

**Edit:** I'm sorry, I forgot to add the biblatex package option `safeinputenc` in the above MWE. This option seems to be the culprit for the missing umlaut in the label. I've updated the MWE to better reflect my original document.

So, is there a way to get a correct label despite using `safeinputenc`? I use this option in order to circumvent the declaration of some unicode chars like ǧ for which I otherwise had to add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01E7}{\v{g}}
```

What is the best practice for using those chars not interpretable by inputenc's utf8 mode?

Comment: Load inputenc with the correct encoding of your file. But I'm wondering if it is deliberate or an oversight that you don't get the Umlaut without inputenc.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I guess it's deliberate, but maybe one could ask for a change.

Comment: You could remove the safeinputenc option and call biber with the option `--output_safechars` instead. Imho you should also add an issue to the tracker of biber.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy to achieve.

Add the following two lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The first line tells LaTeX which encoding your files are using. The second line tells LaTeX to embed the real umlaut-characters *as characters* in the pdf, or you will get `John M¨uller` if you copy text out of your pdf.

Then you have to change the encoding of your documents to `UTF-8 without BOM`; maybe you should alos exchange all umlaut-commands `{\"u}` with their characters `ü` etc., but it's not necesary, see egregs command

In my tests I always get problems if I want to use UTF-8 with `filecontents`, so in this case better create a real file `test.bib`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}%I get a warning, if I don't add it.
\addbibresource{test.bib}%the correct command

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Content of `test.bib`:

```
@Article{Morgan,
  Title   = {Article title},
  Author  = {Müller, John},
  Journal = {Journal title},
  Year    = {2014}
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It works also with `author={M{\"u}ller, John}`; the essential bit is loading `inputenc`.

Comment: you're right, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @musicman: I'm sorry, I had a mistake in my MWE. I have updated the question accordingly.